# $rootScope:infdig error caused by filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ng-repeat to print a list of items and using a custom filter to do some operations.The HTML code is

```
<ul class="list">
      <li class="item item-text-wrap" ng-repeat="item in searchJson | customFilter:search.value">
      <div class="row row-center row-height">
      <font class="text_color">
        <span ng-bind-html="highlight(item.name, search.value)"></span>
      </font>
      </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

The CustomFliter is

```
.filter('customFilter', function () {
 return function (arr,searchString) {
 var names = [];
 var ans = [];
 var item = {};


 if(!searchString){
        return arr;
    }
 searchString = searchString.toLowerCase();
    angular.forEach(arr, function(item){
    if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
      names.push(item);
    }
   else{ 
    if(item.metadata.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) !== -1){
        ans.push(item);
      }
    }
    });
//want to add a header for names
if(names.length!=0)
{
  item['name']='<font color="black"><b>Most relevant results</b</font>'
  names.splice(0,0,angular.copy(item));

}
//want to add a header for questions
if(ans.length!=0)
 {
   item['name']='<font color="black"><b> Other relevant results</b></font>'
   ans.splice(0,0,angular.copy(item));
 }
return names.concat(ans);
};
})
```

Everything works fine without the splice condition(ng-repeat).In the presence of splice am getting $rootScope.infdig error.I went through these links https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider

It is very clear that we cannot add items during digest cycle.Is there a way to add a header dynamically.Can anyone help on this issue.

I tried using collection-repeat and it is working fine but the problem is, If I navigate to the second page and come to this page again nothing is visible unless I make a contact to the screen.How to fix this issue???

Comment: //want to add a header for names
if(names.length!=0)
{
  item['name']='<font color="black"><b>Most relevant results</b</font>'
  names.splice(0,0,angular.copy(item));

}
//want to add a header for questions
if(ans.length!=0)
 {
   item['name']='<font color="black"><b> Other relevant results</b></font>'
   ans.splice(0,0,angular.copy(item));
 } .... see this way of doing things is not angular like .. you should put this html stuff in your view.. and manage it using n-show/ng-hide/ng-if .. your filter should return the items in the searchjson that match the search term